# How can I download macOS Sierra installer

Tags: macos

The latest macOS version at the moment is **High Sierra** (10.13), and I can't find the installer for macOS **Sierra** (10.12) at the App Store. How/where can I download the installer for macOS Sierra?

Comment: Is your Mac not capable of running High Sierra?